# Web API call failed in device mode but working in emulater in Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, asp.net-web-api2

In my project I have deployed my web api in cloud server and getting the data from that service. In ripple emulator it is working perfectly. But when I debuging in device mode  (Android Tab) it is enable to call the service.It didn't show any specific error message also.

here in my index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!--angularJS local storage-->
    <script src="js/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <script src="app/services/authIntercepterService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/productService.js"></script>


    <script src="app/controllers/mainAppController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/productsController.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

and Here is product service

```
app.factory('productService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', 'ngAuthSettings', function ($http, $q, localStorageService, ngAuthSettings) {

    var serviceBase = ngAuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri;

    var productServiceFactory = {};


    var _getAllDishCategories = function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: serviceBase + "api/Product/GetAllDishCategories"
        }).success(function (response) {

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status, header, config) {

            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    };

    var _getProductById = function (productId) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: serviceBase + "api/Product/GetProductById",
            params: {
                productId: productId
            }
        }).success(function (response) {

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status, header, config) {

            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    productServiceFactory.getAllDishCategories = _getAllDishCategories;
    productServiceFactory.getProductById = _getProductById;

    return productServiceFactory;

}]);
```

Here is my Web API controller

```
using FandBClassLibrary;
using FandBViewModel.Product;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace FandBWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Product")]
    public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        #region Member variable

        private IProductManager productManager;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor 

        public ProductController()
        {

        }

        public ProductController(IProductManager productManager)
        {
            this.productManager = productManager;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Post Methods

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetAllDishCategories")]
        public List<DishCategoryViewModel> GetAllDishCategories()
        {
            var dcList= productManager.GetAllDishCategories();

            return dcList;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetProductById")]
        public ProductViewModel GetProductById(string productId)
        {
            var productdetails = productManager.GetProductById(productId);

            return productdetails;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here I have enable CROS in startup class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(FandBWebAPI.Startup))]

namespace FandBWebAPI
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to resolve this issue please?

Thanks,
Erandika

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to install the whitelist plugin. After that it start to work. You can use following command to install the plugin. To do that in command prompt go to your project folder and execute following command.

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**

More info please refer this [URL](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

Thanks,
Erandika.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer, it solved my problem too!

Comment: now cordova 10 don't support this plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you Web API is hosted locally it is hard to reach it from your device.

The best thing you could to is to put your Web API on an online domain, so you can approach it via WWW.

As example:

What your probably using at the moment is: `http://localhost:port/api/movies`

If you have a website and an app with permission to the internet you can do: http://yourwebsite.com/api/movies.

For more question send me a message.

Goodluck!

Comment: Hi Gio, My web service already hosted in cloud so I already have required url format. Issue was I have to installed the whitelist pluging to my project. After that it was start to work. Anyway Thanks for your help.